# Mail Server Can't Receive Email But Can Send Email - Postfix, Dovecot, Postgresql

Tags: ubuntu, postfix, postgresql, dovecot

I have server where I want to set up a mail server to let me receive and send email from my domain. I'm currently having a problem where while I am can not receive mails. Sending emails works perfect.

I'm going off of this script, which shows how to configure a mail server using Postfix, Dovecot, and using Postgresql as the backend (https://gist.github.com/solusipse/7ed8e1da104baaee3f05).

/etc/postfix/main.cf:

```
relay_domains =
virtual_alias_maps = proxy:pgsql:/etc/postfix/virtual_alias_maps.cf
virtual_mailbox_domains = proxy:pgsql:/etc/postfix/virtual_mailbox_domains.cf
virtual_mailbox_maps = proxy:pgsql:/etc/postfix/virtual_mailbox_maps.cf
virtual_mailbox_base = /home/vmail
virtual_mailbox_limit = 512000000
virtual_minimum_uid = 5000
virtual_transport = virtual
virtual_uid_maps = static:5000
virtual_gid_maps = static:5000
local_transport = virtual
local_recipient_maps = 
transport_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/transport

smtpd_sasl_auth_enable = yes
smtpd_sasl_type = dovecot
smtpd_sasl_path = private/auth
smtpd_recipient_restrictions = permit_mynetworks, permit_sasl_authenticated, reject_unauth_destination
smtpd_sasl_security_options = noanonymous
smtpd_sasl_tls_security_options = 
smtpd_tls_auth_only = yes
smtpd_tls_cert_file = /etc/ssl/private/server.crt
smtpd_tls_key_file = /etc/ssl/private/server.key
smtpd_sasl_local_domain = 
broken_sasl_auth_clients = yes
smtpd_tls_loglevel = 1
html_directory = /usr/share/doc/postfix/html
queue_directory = /var/spool/postfix
mydestination = localhost
```

/etc/dovecot/dovecot.conf:

```
protocols = imap
auth_mechanisms = plain
passdb {
    driver = sql
    args = /etc/dovecot/dovecot-sql.conf
}
userdb {
    driver = sql
    args = /etc/dovecot/dovecot-sql.conf
}
service auth {
    unix_listener /var/spool/postfix/private/auth {
    group = postfix
    mode = 0660
    user = postfix
    }
    user = root
}
mail_home = /home/vmail/%d/%u
mail_location = maildir:~
ssl_cert = </etc/ssl/private/server.crt
ssl_key = </etc/ssl/private/server.key
```

/var/logs/mail.log:

```
Apr 17 19:46:18 v22015072919626549 postfix/smtpd[8837]: connect from ***
Apr 17 19:46:18 v22015072919626549 postfix/smtpd[8837]: 62D6A3E0DC9: client=***
Apr 17 19:46:18 v22015072919626549 postfix/cleanup[8843]: 62D6A3E0DC9: message-id=***
Apr 17 19:46:18 v22015072919626549 postfix/smtpd[8837]: disconnect from ***
Apr 17 19:46:18 v22015072919626549 postfix/qmgr[9001]: 62D6A3E0DC9: from=<***>, size=1160, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Apr 17 19:46:18 v22015072919626549 postfix/virtual[8844]: 62D6A3E0DC9: to=<***>, relay=virtual, delay=0.05, delays=0.01/0.01/0/0.02, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (delivered to maildir)
Apr 17 19:46:18 v22015072919626549 postfix/qmgr[9001]: 62D6A3E0DC9: removed
```

Comment: surely you get an error message in the mailbox you're sending from? - this is the all important piece of information you know!

Comment: @Rob-d I get no error message.

Comment: Have you checked things like MX record, firewall, etc.?

Answer (score 1):

> Apr 17 19:46:18 v22015072919626549 postfix/virtual[8844]: 62D6A3E0DC9: to=<***>, relay=virtual, delay=0.05, delays=0.01/0.01/0/0.02, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (**delivered to maildir**)

So Postfix is delivering the mail *somewhere*, but we don't yet know *where*.

> I am can not receive mails. Sending emails works perfect.

So **are you sure Postfix delivers mail *where Dovecot is looking?***

The e-mail *does* get stored somewhere; the log excerpt plainly says so. According to the man page on the Postfix web site, [virtual(8)](http://www.postfix.org/virtual.8.html) constructs the mailbox pathname as `$virtual_mailbox_base/$virtual_mailbox_maps(recipient)` "where *recipient* is the full recipient address.". [virtual_mailbox_base comes from postfix.cf](http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#virtual_mailbox_base) and in your configuration is set to `/home/vmail`, and your `virtual_mailbox_maps` setting looks reasonably valid as well (and if that was where the problem was, you'd probably be seeing Postfix complaining about it).

That is mirrored by Dovecot's configuration `mail_home = /home/vmail/%d/%u`. But in Dovecot, you are *also* setting `mail_location = maildir:~`.

Based on [VirtualUsers/Home](http://wiki2.dovecot.org/VirtualUsers/Home) and [MailLocation](http://wiki.dovecot.org/MailLocation) both on the Dovecot Wiki, it looks like this means that Dovecot is looking for "qmail-style" (also known as Maildir) `cur`, `new` and `tmp` directly under /home/vmail/something/something. **Is that where your *Postfix virtual mailbox map* is configured to deliver the emails for the recipients?**

**You should be double-checking that the two configurations are in sync. I'm guessing they aren't,** and that this is causing the two pieces of software -- which really have next to nothing to do with each other -- to work with different maildir locations. That would explain why both claim that everything is fine, but that they see different views of reality.

It's possible that turning on [dont_remove](http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#dont_remove) may help you diagnose this, by causing Postfix to leave mail spool files on disk after the final delivery completes. (Mail spool files are normally deleted after successful delivery.)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried telnetting directly to your server on port 25 from another box? One of the most common mistakes is to have `iptables` block incoming `tcp/25`. If this gets rejected, you just need to allow incoming `tcp/25` through `iptables`.

Comment: Yes this is working. Please see my log file